# xcode update from 3.1.2 to 3.1.4

Tags: xcode

does updating xcode from 3.1.2 to 3.1.4 for iPhone development really required approximately 3GB of free space?

Here are the steps that I took:
1. download this file iphone_sdk_3.1.2_with_xcode_3.1.4__leopard__9m2809.dmg
2. uncheck 3.0 SDK and 2.2 SDK

(the first checkbox for interface builder, quartz etc can't be unchecked right?)

Just want to confirm coz I'm running out of disk space and want to make sure I'm not installing unnecessary things.

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will take that much free disk space on installation, but a lot of the old files will be overwritten during the installation. It assumes that there isn't a previous installation and will not let you install unless you have the required space.

I wouldn't worry about disk space if you already have a previous version installed as the footprint will be about the same in theory, unless you are adding all kinds of random features you didn't have before.